# SVN server hosting company shutting down, and I need a backup of repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

I just logged onto http://www.ezsvn.com, that hosts my SVN repository. I have been paying monthly for hundreds of commits.

They're shutting down, and their support is nonexistent.

Can I get a backup of my repository from my machine?  I’m using Windows.

Comment: This is a good question. You would need a way to make a remote SVN dump, which is not possible using run-off-the-mill `svnadmin` AFAIK. All the programs I can see are for Linux. In the meantime, until something comes up, if they could shut down anytime and it's really a matter of hours, consider doing some manual checkouts of your most important revisions using Tortoise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have shell access:

http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_backup_and_restore

If you don't have shell access (look at both the original answer and also the comments re: `svnsync`):

http://moelhave.dk/2006/07/remote-mirroring-a-subversion-svn-repository/

Comment: This will probably not help because the repo is not a local one, and there is no command-line access on the remote server (I assume).

Comment: Added an option for non-local.

Comment: @Dav I came across that too, but the svk link is dead.

Comment: The `svnsync` referenced in the comments below should still exist; also Google knows where `svk` is: http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage

Comment: aah, `svnsync` looks like the missing link. You will put that into your answer, right? Because I think that should be available as a Windows binary along with the standard svn package and is probably the perfect solution.

Comment: thanks for the help guys, what ive done is made some backups of the last 5 commits, so at least i have those, is there a way i can combone them into a new repo ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to run `svnadmin` on their server, it'll be no problem, and I see Dav has already linked to instructions for that.

Now, if you don't have access to run `svnadmin`, as far as I know it's not possible to use the SVN client itself (maybe TortoiseSVN for you) to copy the entire repository. (**EDIT**: never mind, I guess that was wrong. I'll leave the git info here just for the fun of it though.)  But you can convert a whole Subversion repository to git, and here are instructions for doing that: http://pauldowman.com/2008/07/26/how-to-convert-from-subversion-to-git/ From there, you might be able to convert the git repository back into an SVN repository on another server. I know it's not really the answer you were looking for but if nothing else works, it will at least let you save your project's history in some form. (And hey, you could take it as an excuse to switch to distributed version control, which is all the rage these days)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want/need the full history of your repository, you'll have to either get a dumpfile from the provider or get it yourself - some of the responses so far have addressed this already.

Another option: if you are not concerned with past revisions, but want your repo at it's latest state, just checkout the head revision, and export it to a separate location on your computer. That way, you have all your work to this point. You could then keep that as a backup, or possibly create an SVN account elsewhere, and import the exported copy into a fresh repo, then you would be back in business.